# Why GCC warns when casting an uninitialized volatile pointer to `void`?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, warnings, language-lawyer

Consider following:

```
int *volatile x;
(void)x;
```

GCC (from 5.x to 7.x) complains about it when `-Wall` is enabled:

> warning: 'x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

The clang is silent about it.

For some reason, removing the `volatile` eliminates the warning.

Does the standard say that casting a `volatile` pointer even to `void` is undefined, while casting a normal pointer is fine? Or is that a GCC bug?

---

**Disclaimer:** The question is tagged as C/C++ on purpose. The GCC gives the same warning for both languages, and I'm interested of there is any difference.

Comment: Seems like a GCC bug to me

Comment: Well, x _is_ uninitialised.

Comment: @NeilButterworth But then why GCC doesn't complain about non-volatile pointers?

Comment: Because when x is not volatile `(void)x;` can be optimized out, but when it's volatile `(void)x;` evaluates into an access.

Comment: @cleblanc But it's a no-op anyway, isn't it? I wonder what does the standard say...

Comment: Warnings are issued at the compiler's discretion - if the internal  workings of the compiler don't produce a warning, that's tough, but something that can only be argued about by examining those workings.

Comment: The Standard says (C11 §6.7.3 7): "What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined."

Comment: I guess it's about that accessing a volatile object produces side effect (C11 §5.1.2.3/2), so it cannot be optimized out.

Comment: For the record, MSVC behaves as in the question.

Comment: Also for the record, there's a huge difference between `int * volatile`, and `volatile int *`. And frankly, there's no practical use for `int * volatile`.

Comment: @user3386109 Assume I want to profile a function which returns an `int *`, and I don't want the compiler to optimise any calculations. Assigning the result to `int *volatile` makes sense to me.

Comment: I disagree. If you declare the variable as `volatile int *`, then any code that actually uses the pointer can't be optimized out. And if you **aren't** using the pointer, then what are you profiling really? And btw, there are better ways to prevent the compiler from optimizing things out.

Comment: @user3386109 Assume the function finds an element in an array and returns `int *` to it. I don't want to actually check what was found, I want to see how quickly it was found, so I don't need to actually use the pointer. *"there are better ways"* I hope so, but which ones?

Comment: That might be a good question to ask in a new post. Show us the function that you're actually trying to profile.

Comment: @user3386109 Here it is: http://pastebin.com/B33TppB7 *"a good question to ask in a new post"* I don't what to know that that much yet. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135713/discussion-between-holyblackcat-and-user3386109).

Comment: @user3386109: The declaration `int*volatile` would be reasonable for a pointer that was used by an interrupt service routine, DMA hardware, etc. to read data that was never going to change.  Using `int const*volatile` would also work in that case, but I don't think the `const` would be necessary for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++, this is controlled by [[expr]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr#12), which says that `(void) x` applies the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` (i.e., reads the value of `x`) only if `x` is a glvalue of volatile-qualified type. Therefore, if `x` is volatile-qualified, then `(void) x` reads its value (which yields an indeterminate value and triggers undefined behavior). If `x` isn't volatile-qualified, then  `(void) x` doesn't apply the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the behavior is well-defined.

Comment: Doesn't `volatile` mean, on almost any practical implementation, that a compiler should expect that the programmer knows things the compiler doesn't about means by whih the storage in question could change?  The Standard doesn't require that any such means exist, nor that a compiler make provision for such means if in fact none exist, but many kinds of programming involve such things, and thus a quality general-purpose implementation should almost always presume that something could happen to set the value in question without its knowledge.

Comment: @supercat Not exactly. `1.9 8 Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine. <...and as well as some other things is...> referred to as the observable behavior of the program.` The standard only says that reads/writes to `volatile` are *observable behaviour* and can't be reordered/changed/removed.

Comment: If you think about it, your definition is different. It would require `volatile` to always make objects atomic, as well as it would require compilers to allow type-punning using `volatile` unions (since it would be impossible to tell if a different union field was made active or not.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The intention of the Standard is to give broad latitude to define things in ways which are reasonable for the intended application field and target platform.  If two physical effects of two different instruction sequences would be identical on the target platform, I see no reason why the Standard should prefer one over the other.  A compiler which would assume that the instruction sequences would be equivalent should document that assumption, so the programmer can exercise appropriate caution if code might run on different but "compatible" hardware where different things...

Comment: ...might be observable.  If there is some sensible reason why implementations for some particular platform and application field would not treat volatile accesses as atomic, then such implementations should not be expected to treat them as such.  I can't think of any particular scenario where it would be reasonable for a compiler not to recognize aliasing between something which is written as `volatile` and then read as `volatile`, no matter what the types happened to be, but it might conceivably be reasonable for some combination of platform and application field.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: What's important is to understand that the Standard gives broad latitude in cases where some behavior might possibly be reasonable in some rare cases, but that does not mean programmers have no right to expect compilers not to engage in such behavior in the more common cases where it would be patently unreasonable.  I've seen no evidence that they intended that programmers in the year 2017 should be burdened by the limitations of unusual architectures outside of the rare cases where they are writing code specifically for use with such architectures.

Answer (score 4):

One of the behaviours of `volatile` for plain old data type like `int *` is to prevent the compiler from optimizing away the reading and writing to the variable. Please notice that `int *` here could be whatever like `float` or `int`.

So `(void)x` is meaning "read x and do nothing with the result" because `x` is `volatile`. If you read `x` and it's not pinned to a fixed position in memory (which the compiler might not know, only the linker does), then you're actually using it *uninitialized*.

If it's not volatile, although the compiler might read `x` anyway, it will likely avoid/optimize this (since it's a no-op), and silent the warning.

clang takes the safe road here, and since the linker directive could pin the variable x to some position (without clang knowing about it), consider that it's not worth triggering a warning without more evidence it's an issue.

Comment: An object is unitialized before a value is assigned to it. The object has a location, even if it is uninitialized. There is no "pinning" going on in this question; the variable has a location. If the code were trying to dereference the variable, what you say might make senses, but the statement is not `(void)*x;`.

Comment: If on the linker option you set the position of the pointer to be 0xDEADBEEF (whatever), then you don't care about the *content* of the pointer, thus it's no more uninitialized. I'm not speaking about the content of the memory pointed to. Currently, x being a `int *` does not make any difference with x being a `int` for the compiler's reaction/warning message.

Comment: How do you set the "position of a pointer" with the linker? `x` is just an ordinary variable, presumably allocated automatically since the context indicates that it is part of a function body (although my comment doesn't really change if it is statically allocated at file scope). Automatic variables don't even exist at link time. Had `x` been declared `extern`, your comment would make sense (but the warning wouldn't be produced).

Comment: It's hard to say with only 2 lines of code. If you want to set the position of the variable, you'll need another translation unit where it's declared as extern (only need to be declared once) in a specific section. I don't think it's the point here, since the compiler only deal with a single translation unit here. Then a linker script maps the section to some specific address, see http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/SECTIONS.html#SECTIONS

Comment: If you are planning to map a symbol to a specific hardware register (for example), then you should declare it `extern` in *every* translation unit and then assign its value with the linker `--defsym` option (with GNU ld, at least). As I said, the `extern` declaration will suppress the error message because the compiler then knows that the symbol is initialized elsewhere (or at least, it has reason to believe that).

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is declared `volatile` then to cast away the `volatile`, just as it is undefined behaviour to cast away the const from a variable declared const. See `Annex J.2` of the `C Standard`:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> — An attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through
>   use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type (6.7.3).

Somewhere I have read and noted down about rules of using `volatile` are:

- Use volatile for variables that might change "unexpectedly".
- Use volatile for automatic variables in routines that use setjmp().
- To force volatile semantics on a particular access, take the address of the variable and cast it to (volatile WHATEVER *), dereferencing the cast expression to get the value.
- Sometimes volatile is a reasonable way to get around problems with code generation in compilers that have conformance problems in some areas, eg, the gcc compiler on x86 with semantics of assigning or casting to double. Don't do this just haphazardly, since if it's unnecessary code quality will very likely go down.
- Unless you really know what you're doing and why you're doing it, if you're using volatile you're likely doing something wrong. Try to find another way to solve the problem, and if you still have to use volatile code
  up a nice small example and post to comp.lang.c and ask for helpful suggestions.

Comment: I don't think `(void)x` counts as casting away the `volatile`. Even if it is, casting to `volatile void` gives the same warning.

Answer (score 2):

Any access to a volatile object is part of your program's *observable behavior* in both C and C++. *Observable behavior* is an important concept in both C and C++.

Your code formally reads a volatile pointer `x`. I would guess that GCC considers it a rather serious issue when part of program observable behavior involves an uninitialized value.

The moment you remove `volatile`, reading of `x` ceases to be a part of observable behavior. Hence the warning disappears as well.

Comment: Right, it makes sense. What I'm not sure about is what exacly access means? Do statements without any effect count as access?

Comment: The fact that the variable is `volatile` should generally imply that its value might become set by means unknown to the compiler, so there's generally no such thing as an "uninitialized" `volatile` variable.  If the variable has automatic duration and its address is not taken, however, gcc might decide that there is no mechanism via which anything else in the universe could cause the variable's value to change.

Answer (score 1):

If the misaligned pointer is dereferenced, the program may terminate abnormally. On some architectures, the cast alone may cause a loss of information even if the value is not dereferenced if the types involved have differing alignment requirements.

The C Standard, 6.3.2.3, paragraph 7 say's:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a
>   pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting
>   pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior
>   is undefined.

Comment: That's more or less what I've expected, but the quote seems to be not quite revelant, since I'm not casting to a pointer type.